# this constructor does not return component name on deployed environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

console.log(this) returns component object in the component and I can get its name by this.constructor.name in local environment but it does not work in deployed environment and it returns 'e' instead of the component.

on local
    console.log(this)
    couponCampaignPage {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, state: Object…}

on server
     console.log(this)
     e {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, state: Object…}

Does anyone know which makes impact on this? I am a newbie to react. Should I look into browserify to solve this?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I found out that it is uglifier which minify javascript but still I did not figure out  which option will keep component name untouched.

Comment: https://github.com/lautis/uglifier/issues/107

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4915 Someone had suffered from the same issue and filed an issue